# For which of the following values of $\theta$ is $tan(\theta)$ always greater than $cos(\theta)$?

Tags: trigonometry

This was on a SAT Math IIC problem, and I had a hard time grasping this question. I know in the 3rd quadrant, tangent is always positive while cosine is always negative. Hence, I presumed that the only time this was possible was in the 3rd quadrant ($180^\circ$ < $\theta$ < $270^\circ$). None of the answer choices, however, has this as a solution.

These are the answer choices:

(A) $0^\circ$ < $\theta$ < $45^\circ$

(B) $45^\circ$ < $\theta$ < $90^\circ$

(C) $90^\circ$ < $\theta$ < $135^\circ$

(D) $135^\circ$ < $\theta$ < $180^\circ$

(E) not possible

Since I could not find the corresponding answer choice, I put (E) but the answer key says it's (B). Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Tan has a period of $/pi$ not $2 /pi$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a less rigorous solution (presumably more suited for the SAT), recall that $\tan(\theta)$ is the slope of the line with angle $\theta$ in the unit circle and $\cos(\theta)$ is the x-coordinate of where that line intersects the unit circle.

In the first quadrant, $\tan(\theta)$ would be greater than $1$ if $\theta>45^{\circ}$. But we also know that the maximum value that $\cos(\theta)$ obtains is $1$, which happens at $\theta=0^{\circ}$. Putting these two facts together gives us (B).

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I'm still unsure, however, why you would need the second bit of information: "But we also know that the maximum value that cos($\theta$) obtains is 1, which happens at $\theta$ = $0^\circ$."

Comment: Since we know that $\tan(\theta)>1$ on that range and the second fact gives us $\cos(\theta)\leq 1$ for all $\theta$, we can conclude.

Answer (score 0):

You have to study: $$\tan(x)>\cos(x) \leftrightarrow \frac{\sin^2(x)+\sin(x)-1}{\cos(x)}>0$$
First we study the numerator: $N\geq0$; we have:
$$\sin^2(x)+\sin(x)-1\geq0$$
Let $t=\sin(x)$, we obtain a quadratic equation, so:
$$t=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
The angle $x$ for which $\sin^2(x)+\sin(x)-1=0$ are: $$x_1=\arcsin\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right) \: \vee \: x_2=\pi-\arcsin\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$$
Using the rules of trigonometry, we arrive at:
$$N\geq0\rightarrow\arcsin\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)+2k\pi\leq x \leq \pi-\arcsin\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)+2k\pi$$
For the denominator we have to study $\cos(x)\>0$, so we have:
$$\cos(x)>0\leftrightarrow 0+2k\pi<x<\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \; \vee \; \frac{3\pi}{2}+2k\pi<x<2\pi+2k\pi$$
From here, it's very easy to see that:
$$\frac{\sin^2(x)+\sin(x)-1}{\cos(x)}>0\rightarrow\arcsin\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)+2k\pi\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\; \vee \; \pi-\arcsin\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)+2k\pi \leq x \leq \frac{3\pi}{2}+2k\pi $$
Computing the values of $\arcsin\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$ and $\pi-\arcsin\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$ we can say that the correct answer is $B$.

Comment: How can you conclude that tan($x$) > cos($x$) I.F.F. the statement on the right?

Comment: Simply move $\cos(x)$ and then sum $\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}-\cos(x)$

Comment: Thanks, the product law is going to help us in the problem? I don't see how it will.

Comment: $tan(x) = cos(x) \Rightarrow\; x=sin^-1(\frac(ssqrt(5)-1}{2)$

Comment: @yagayeet: please see my edits.

Answer (score 0):

$ tan(x) = cos(x) \Rightarrow\; $
$  x=\sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}$

So, the whole satisfying interval  is (B) 45∘ < θ < 90∘